# How to remove spaces from special characters?

Tags: python

So i was working on an python assignment that had this question:
***Define a function that accepts a sentence and calculate the number of letters(Upper-Lower
separately),words,digits,vowels,consonant and special symbols in it.***
I wrote the following code for this:

```
def calc():
    ucount=lcount=dcount=vcount=ccount=0
    a = input("Enter the statement :")
    
    for b in a:
        if b.isupper():
            ucount+=1
        elif b.islower():
            lcount+=1
        elif b.isdigit():
            dcount+=1
    for b in a:
        if b>"a" and b<="z" or b>"A" and b<="Z" and a not in "AEIOUaeiou":
            ccount+=1
        elif b in "AEIOUaeiou":
            vcount+=1
        

    b = a.split()
    wcount=len(b)
    c = ucount+lcount+dcount
    scount= len(a)-c
    return ucount,lcount,dcount,vcount,ccount,scount,wcount
u,l,d,v,c,s,w=calc()
print("Number of uppercase characters =", u)
print("Number of lowerrcase characters =", l)
print("Number of digits=", d)
print("Number of vowels =", v)
print("Number of consonant =", c)
print("Number of words =", w)
print("Number of special symbols =", s)
```

The output is coming but the problem is it is also taking the spaces i give as special characters for example:

```
Enter the statement :My name is Kunal Kumar
Number of uppercase characters = 3
Number of lowerrcase characters = 19
Number of digits= 0
Number of vowels = 5
Number of consonant = 17
Number of words = 5
Number of special symbols = 4
```

Please help me to find out how I should remove these spaces from the special characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replace the spaces in string `a` with empty strings prior to computing `scount`:

```
scount= len(a.replace(' ',''))-c
```

Comment: Thanks my G:-). I would have upvoted your answer but i don't have 15 reputation mate. So like I am really sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [replace method](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-string-strip/)

```
a.replace(" ", "")
```

Comment: `strip()` will only deal with the leading and trailing characters in the string, but will not handle the whitespaces between words.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the code below

```
def calc():
ucount=lcount=dcount=vcount=ccount=0
a = input("Enter the statement :")

for b in a:
    if b.isupper():
        ucount+=1
    elif b.islower():
        lcount+=1
    elif b.isdigit():
        dcount+=1
for b in a:
    if b>"a" and b<="z" or b>"A" and b<="Z":
        if b not in "AEIOUaeiou":
            ccount+=1
    if b in "AEIOUaeiou":
        vcount+=1

b = a.split()
wcount=len(b)
c = ucount+lcount+dcount
scount= len(a)-c
return ucount,lcount,dcount,vcount,ccount,scount,wcount
```

I have already tested it.

Please make a commit after check.

Comment: This just solved my vowel problem mate but, it did not solve the space problem. Thanks for your effort though mate(❁´◡`❁)